# How I pass a delegate prototype to a method?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

SO lets say in my class I have:

```
public delegate bool MyFunc(int param);
```

How can I then do this

```
someObj.PassMeADelegateToExamine(this.MyFunc); // not possible!?!
```

SO that I can examine the delegate and perhaps use reflection or something idk to find out it's return type and any params it might have?

Basically if I can transform it into an (uncallable) Action object that woul dbe grand

Comment: "find out it's return type", "transform it into an ... Action"... `Action` returns `void`.

Comment: Well, the equivelent would be Func<int,bool> - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The "prototype" is just a new Type definition - it's not an actual instance that you would use directly.  In your case, MyFunc is the delegate `Type`, not an actual delegate.

You could do:

```
void PassMeADelegateTypeToExamine(Type type) { ... }
```

And then call it:

```
someObj.PassMeADelegateTypeToExamine(MyFunc);
```

Comment: IIRC, unless MyFunc is a Type, and not a delegate name (like the OP posted), this isn't going to compile. You'd need `typeof(MyFunc)`.

Answer (score 1):

A delegate declaration is a type declaration, just like `struct` and `class`. So you can use

```
typeof(MyFunc)
```

To find the delegate's return type and arguments, you must look at the delegate type's `Invoke` method:

```
MethodInfo invokeMethod = typeof(MyFunc).GetMethod("Invoke");
Type returnType = invokeMethod.ReturnType;
ParameterInfo[] parameterInfos = invokeMethod.GetParameters();
```

A delegate is pretty much a class with some conventional methods like `Invoke`. When you use a delegate instance like so

```
func(args)
```

This is translated internally to

```
func.Invoke(args)
```

Which is why there is no special **DelegateInfo** type in the reflection namespace: the `Invoke` method's **MethodInfo** tells you all you need.

Now, if you'd want to call a delegate instance dynamically, you can either use reflection and call `Invoke` on your **MethodInfo** or make sure your delegate variable is typed as **Delegate**, which gives you access to the `DynamicInvoke` method:

```
Delegate func = ...;
object result = func.DynamicInvoke(arg1, arg2);
```

Comment: This is truly great stuff man, thanks so much I will accept your answer when it lets me.